# Breeze.js and knockout.js applybindings a second time

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze

The first time i click the Button everything is bound correct. But when i click the button a second time all the old values are still bound to my view? How can i reapply new bindings to my breeze.js viewmodel?

JS

```
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('/breeze/corporations');

$("#myButton").click(function () {

    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Corporations").where("Name", "startsWith", "Zen");

    manager.executeQuery(query)
                   .then(querySucceeded)
                   .fail(queryFailed);

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        var ib = $("#infoBox")[0];
        ko.applyBindings(data, ib);
    }
});
```

Html

```
<div id="infoBox""> 
    <ul data-bind="foreach: results">
        <li>
            <strong><span data-bind="text:City"></span></strong>
            <span data-bind="text:Name"></span>     
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not reapply bindings. You should update only data. You should not apply bindings multiple times to the same DOM elements.

Comment: ok, thanks. i simply added a variable `isapplied` and checked for it's status

Comment: edit: view still isn't updated. same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150023/breeze-js-query-does-not-update-knockout-view?noredirect=1#comment24824907_17150023